# foreach binding vars problem

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following array content:

```
  Array ( [achternaam] => Jansen [roepnaam] => Theo )
```

Now i want to use this code

```
 foreach ($values as $r) {
    $achternaam = $r['achternaam'];
    $roepnaam = $r['roepnaam'];      
 }
```

When want to echo the $achternaam and $voornaam the values are empty.
Does anyone know how to bind this variables to eachother.

The result should be $achternaam = Jansen and $roepnaam = Theo.

Tnx for helping!

Comment: Foreach doesn't give so-called 'associative arrays'. So you could do $achternaam = $r[0].

Comment: Isn't Theo Jansen the same who designed some beautiful walking mechanisms using genetic algorithms? Cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = array(
    'achternaam' => 'Jansen',
    'roepnaam' => 'Theo'
);
```

The elements of `$values` are strings, not arrays. To access the `achternaam` and `roepnaam` values, you need to remove the foreach:

```
$achternaam = $values['achternaam'];
$roepnaam = $values['roepnaam'];
```

If the positions of the `achternaam` and `roepnaam` keys do not change, you may use `list` as well:

```
list($achternaam, $roepnaam) = $values;
```

This is **only** possible if the keys are in the order `achternaam`, `roepnaam`. I.e. `$values['achternaam']` needs to assigned before `$values['roepnaam']`.

Comment: Can you use a list in a for each loop?

Comment: @DownDown: no problem, you might want to read http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php too

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$values = array('achternaam' => 'Jansen', 'roepnaam' => 'Theo');
list($achternaam, $roepnaam) = $values;
```

try it though...

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested array if you want to have more than one person:

```
<?php
$values = array(
  array(
    'achternaam' => 'Jansen',
    'voornaam' => 'Theo',
    'club' => 'Ajax'
  )
);

foreach ($values as $r) {
  $achternaam = $r['achternaam'];
  $roepnaam = $r['roepnaam'];      
  echo $roepnaam . ' ' . $achternaam;      
}
```

If you want to keep using that array though, you can do it without foreach:

```
<?php
$values = array(
  'achternaam' => 'Jansen',
  'voornaam' => 'Theo',
  'club' => 'Ajax'
);

$achternaam = $values['achternaam'];
$roepnaam = $values['roepnaam'];      
echo $roepnaam . ' ' . $achternaam;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're misunderstanding how `foreach` works. For each iteration of the loop, your variable `$r` has a string value - "Jansen" the first time and "Theo" the second.

The result you're trying to achieve can be done like this:

```
foreach($values as $k => $r) {
    $$k = $r;
}
```

Be careful where your array keys are coming from though - as this code could overwrite other sensitive variables in your script.

Comment: That construct can be accomplished with `extract($values)` too.

Answer (score 0):

How about one simple line of code: 
`extract($values)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php